# Reactnative-Xmpp Sending `connect` with no listeners registered

Tags: react-native, xmpp, ejabberd, react-native-ios

For chat tried  [reactnative-xmpp](https://github.com/Coditation/reactnative-xmpp) sample application. In ejabberd log only got "Accepted connection" nothing happens after that.

After some times getting "Sending `connect` with no listeners registered" and "Sending `Close` with no listeners registered." warnings only. Same code works with android without any issues.